# How to allow certain IP's to access a page in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

We have a website running on Nginx in Ubuntu server. The website has an admin page which we want to allow access to the specified IP addresses. I have used the following in the Nginx config, but it doesn't block. Could you please help me to solve it? Thanks.

Website URL: `www.example.com`

Admin page: `https://www.example.com/en/admin/login.php`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /en/admin/ {
                allow 123.123.123.123;
                deny all;
        }

        # Disable directory listing
        autoindex off;

}
```

Comment: Here you display the config for the default and plain http server. Access controls here do not apply to the https server (you refer to a  **`https`** `://www.example.com/en/admin/login.php` ) That is possible defined in a different server block / included configuration snippet. - In other words: you will need define your access controls twice.

Answer (score -3):

Try to switch the deny and allow in order.

```
location /en/admin/ {
deny all;              
allow 123.123.123.123;              
        }
```

Then do nginx -t and restart or reload nginx. Also put location /en/admin before the location /

Comment: `The rules are checked in sequence until the first match is found.` - this will block everything, the second rule will never be checked.